# Understand the insufficient memory report given by the java runtime environment to find out the OOM cause

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory

I am having insufficient memory problems and I am unable to find out the cause.

If I am not wrong, the machine has sufficient memory and also the java heap size is enough. So, the problem should be some other imposed limit which I am not able to discover.

To reduce the causes spectrum I disabled the compressed oops (-XX:-UseCompressedOops).
Also, to simplify the reports, I set the max and min heap size to the same value (-Xmx348m -Xms348m).

The OS is Centos 7 with overcommit disabled (vm.overcommit_memory=2, vm.overcommit_ratio=60, vm.min_free_kbytes=51200, vm.swappiness=80) to avoid the OOM Killer to kill my application. And to compesate that I added swap memory.

Just in case it isn't irrelevant, the machine is a virtual GCP instance with 600MB of physicals RAM and 1600 MB of swap.

After inspecting the report my impression was that there is not enough meta-space virtual space guided by the ">99%" of committed memory. But the `MaxMetaspaceSize` is unlimited, so I discarded that impression.

This is the report:

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 16384 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2976), pid=19661, tid=27722
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.11+9) (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, serial gc, linux-amd64)
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xmx348m -Xms348m -XX:-UseCompressedOops -Xloggc:/home/botofono/actual/logs/gc.log webServer.Boot

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz, 1 cores, 587M, CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Time: Thu Apr 29 22:11:53 2021 UTC elapsed time: 20719.354308 seconds (0d 5h 45m 19s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000558766169800):  JavaThread "Main-akka.actor.internal-dispatcher-339" [_thread_new, id=27722, stack(0x00007f182f8fb000,0x00007f182f9fc000)]

Stack: [0x00007f182f8fb000,0x00007f182f9fc000],  sp=0x00007f182f9fa970,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xeeb895]  VMError::report_and_die(int, char const*, char const*, __va_list_tag*, Thread*, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, int, unsigned long)+0x235
V  [libjvm.so+0xeec763]  VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*, __va_list_tag*)+0x43
V  [libjvm.so+0x6e8370]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*, ...)+0x110
V  [libjvm.so+0xc3d152]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xc2
V  [libjvm.so+0xc33ade]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x2e
V  [libjvm.so+0xc3e920]  os::pd_create_stack_guard_pages(char*, unsigned long)+0x80
V  [libjvm.so+0xe810dc]  JavaThread::create_stack_guard_pages()+0x5c
V  [libjvm.so+0xe82d3c]  JavaThread::run()+0x2c
V  [libjvm.so+0xe7ef9a]  Thread::call_run()+0x16a
V  [libjvm.so+0xc435d8]  thread_native_entry(Thread*)+0xf8


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x000055876617f810, length=23, elements={
0x00007f188008f800, 0x00007f1880094000, 0x00007f18800a8800, 0x00007f18800aa800,
0x00007f18800ad000, 0x00007f18800af000, 0x00007f18800b1000, 0x00007f1880151800,
0x00007f1880989000, 0x00007f1830004800, 0x00007f1880d5e000, 0x00007f184c00b800,
0x00007f184c00d800, 0x00007f18341d2000, 0x00007f1880017000, 0x00007f18301b2000,
0x00007f1838013000, 0x00007f183801e800, 0x00007f184c006000, 0x00007f188084a800,
0x00007f1844226800, 0x00007f18280a7000, 0x0000558766169800
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f188008f800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19712, stack(0x00007f18_8567_5000,0x00007f18_8577_6000)]
  0x00007f1880094000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19713, stack(0x00007f1885574000,0x00007f1885675000)]
  ... some threads removed

Other Threads:
  0x00007f1880087800 VMThread "VM Thread" [stack: 0x00007f1885778000,0x00007f1885878000] [id=19711]
  0x00007f188010e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f1884f6f000,0x00007f188506f000] [id=19719]

Threads with active compile tasks:

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 def new generation   total 106_944K, used 62_805K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95_104K,  60% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185648b2c0, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11_840K,  41% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185993a480, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11_840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237_568K, used 30_327K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237_568K,  12% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185bd9dfc0, 0x00007f185bd9e000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 92_749K, capacity 97_419K, committed 97_536K, reserved 98_304K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000_7f18_89a1_3000,0x0000_7f18_89ac_2000] _byte_map_base: 0x0000_7ed8_fd77_d000

Polling page: 0x00007f1889be0000

Metaspace:

Usage:
   95.14 MB capacity,    90.58 MB ( 95%) used,     3.91 MB (  4%) free+waste,   666.38 KB ( <1%) overhead. 

Virtual space:
     96.00 MB reserved,      95.25 MB (>99%) committed 

Chunk freelists:
62.00 KB

MaxMetaspaceSize: unlimited


CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods': size=120036Kb used=3874Kb max_used=3874Kb free=116161Kb
 bounds [0x00007f1870349000, 0x00007f1870719000, 0x00007f1877882000]
CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods': size=120032Kb used=14201Kb max_used=14201Kb free=105830Kb
 bounds [0x00007f1868e11000, 0x00007f1869bf1000, 0x00007f1870349000]
CodeHeap 'non-nmethods': size=5692Kb used=1350Kb max_used=1376Kb free=4341Kb
 bounds [0x00007f1868882000, 0x00007f1868af2000, 0x00007f1868e11000]
 total_blobs=8839 nmethods=8022 adapters=730
 compilation: enabled
              stopped_count=0, restarted_count=0
 full_count=0

Compilation events (20 events): <removed because I think this is irrelevant>

GC Heap History (16 events):
Event: 5.753 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=0 (full 0):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 72981K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,  76% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1857345530, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 0K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,   0% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000200, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 20877K, capacity 20989K, committed 21248K, reserved 22528K
}
Event: 5.805 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 1):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 0K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 12811K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,   5% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185ac82de0, 0x00007f185ac82e00, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 20877K, capacity 20989K, committed 21248K, reserved 22528K
}
Event: 8.408 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 1):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 71167K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,  74% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185717fc78, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 12811K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,   5% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185ac82de0, 0x00007f185ac82e00, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 34498K, capacity 35182K, committed 35328K, reserved 36864K
}
Event: 8.453 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 2):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 0K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 17823K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,   7% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b167fa0, 0x00007f185b168000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 34498K, capacity 35182K, committed 35328K, reserved 36864K
}
Event: 11.876 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 2):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 95104K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K, 100% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 17823K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,   7% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b167fa0, 0x00007f185b168000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 55383K, capacity 57083K, committed 57088K, reserved 57344K
}
Event: 11.896 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 2):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 5550K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  46% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f18599dbb88, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 17823K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,   7% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b167fa0, 0x00007f185b168000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 55383K, capacity 57083K, committed 57088K, reserved 57344K
}
Event: 12.270 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 2):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 18749K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,  13% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18538e3b30, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  46% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f18599dbb88, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 17823K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,   7% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b167fa0, 0x00007f185b168000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 56949K, capacity 58844K, committed 58880K, reserved 59392K
}
Event: 12.325 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 0K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 23993K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  10% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b76e6c0, 0x00007f185b76e800, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 56949K, capacity 58844K, committed 58880K, reserved 59392K
}
Event: 16.167 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 95104K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K, 100% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 23993K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  10% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b76e6c0, 0x00007f185b76e800, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 76922K, capacity 79828K, committed 79872K, reserved 79872K
}
Event: 16.199 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=5 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 6700K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  56% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1858f6b2e8, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 23993K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  10% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b76e6c0, 0x00007f185b76e800, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 76922K, capacity 79828K, committed 79872K, reserved 79872K
}
Event: 3771.331 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 101804K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K, 100% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  56% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1858f6b2e8, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 23993K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  10% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185b76e6c0, 0x00007f185b76e800, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 85703K, capacity 89394K, committed 89600K, reserved 90112K
}
Event: 3772.694 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=6 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 3802K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  32% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859826b18, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 30327K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  12% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185bd9dfc0, 0x00007f185bd9e000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 85703K, capacity 89394K, committed 89600K, reserved 90112K
}
Event: 10014.891 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=6 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 98906K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K, 100% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  32% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859826b18, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 30327K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  12% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185bd9dfc0, 0x00007f185bd9e000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 91886K, capacity 96588K, committed 96768K, reserved 98304K
}
Event: 10021.354 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=7 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 5346K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  45% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1858e18a80, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 30327K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  12% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185bd9dfc0, 0x00007f185bd9e000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 91886K, capacity 96588K, committed 96768K, reserved 98304K
}
Event: 14674.359 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=7 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 100450K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K, 100% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  45% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1858e18a80, 0x00007f1859470000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185a000000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 30327K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  12% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185bd9dfc0, 0x00007f185bd9e000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 92499K, capacity 97146K, committed 97280K, reserved 98304K
}
Event: 14674.620 GC heap after
{Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 106944K, used 4905K [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185a000000)
  eden space 95104K,   0% used [0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f1852c00000, 0x00007f18588e0000)
  from space 11840K,  41% used [0x00007f1859470000, 0x00007f185993a480, 0x00007f185a000000)
  to   space 11840K,   0% used [0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f18588e0000, 0x00007f1859470000)
 tenured generation   total 237568K, used 30327K [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f1868800000, 0x00007f1868800000)
   the space 237568K,  12% used [0x00007f185a000000, 0x00007f185bd9dfc0, 0x00007f185bd9e000, 0x00007f1868800000)
 Metaspace       used 92499K, capacity 97146K, committed 97280K, reserved 98304K
}

Deoptimization events (20 events): <removed because I think this is irrelevant>

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (20 events): <removed because I think this is irrelevant>

Events (20 events):
Event: 20243.287 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 20243.287 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread exited: 0x0000558766169800
Event: 20303.307 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread added: 0x0000558766169800
Event: 20303.307 Protecting memory [0x00007f182f8fb000,0x00007f182f8ff000] with protection modes 0
Event: 20363.307 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 20363.307 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 20363.307 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread exited: 0x0000558766169800
Event: 20423.327 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread added: 0x0000558766169800
Event: 20423.327 Protecting memory [0x00007f182f8fb000,0x00007f182f8ff000] with protection modes 0
Event: 20429.016 Executing VM operation: ThreadDump
Event: 20429.017 Executing VM operation: ThreadDump done
Event: 20429.017 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 20429.017 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 20483.484 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread exited: 0x0000558766169800
Event: 20543.347 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread added: 0x0000558766169800
Event: 20543.347 Protecting memory [0x00007f182f8fb000,0x00007f182f8ff000] with protection modes 0
Event: 20603.382 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 20603.382 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 20603.382 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread exited: 0x0000558766169800
Event: 20679.594 Thread 0x0000558766169800 Thread added: 0x0000558766169800


Dynamic libraries: <removed because I think this is irrelevant>

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xmx348m -Xms348m -XX:-UseCompressedOops -Xloggc:/home/botofono/actual/logs/gc.log 
java_command: webServer.Boot
java_class_path (initial): <removed because I think this is irrelevant>
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 2                                         {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 364904448                                 {product} {command line}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 364904448                                 {product} {command line}
   size_t MaxNewSize                               = 121634816                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MinHeapDeltaBytes                        = 196608                                    {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t NewSize                                  = 121634816                                 {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 5825164                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122916538                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
   size_t OldSize                                  = 243269632                                 {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122916538                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = false                                {lp64_product} {command line}
     bool UseSerialGC                              = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags
 #2: file=/home/botofono/actual/logs/gc.log all=off,gc=info uptime,level,tags filecount=5,filesize=20480K

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11-0.el7_9.x86_64/bin:/home/botofono/.local/bin:/home/botofono/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Signal Handlers: <removed because I think this is irrelevant>

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
uname:Linux 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 25 17:23:54 UTC 2020 x86_64
OS uptime: 141 days 11:42 hours
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit (soft/hard): STACK 8192k/infinity , CORE 0k/infinity , NPROC 2285/2285 , NOFILE 4096/4096 , AS infinity/infinity , CPU infinity/infinity , DATA infinity/infinity , FSIZE infinity/infinity , MEMLOCK 64k/64k
load average:15.02 4.20 1.48

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:         601120 kB
MemFree:          175096 kB
MemAvailable:     165832 kB
Buffers:              92 kB
Cached:           126708 kB
SwapCached:        33032 kB
Active:           140336 kB
Inactive:         180384 kB
Active(anon):     100956 kB
Inactive(anon):   100868 kB
Active(file):      39380 kB
Inactive(file):    79516 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       1662968 kB
SwapFree:        1256648 kB
Dirty:               120 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        191860 kB
Mapped:            10720 kB
Shmem:              7896 kB
Slab:              55316 kB
SReclaimable:      20700 kB
SUnreclaim:        34616 kB
KernelStack:        3280 kB
PageTables:        12700 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2_023_640 kB
Committed_AS:    1_825_492 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        5776 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359730024 kB
Percpu:              176 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       51188 kB
DirectMap2M:      577536 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB

/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled:
[always] madvise never
/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag (defrag/compaction efforts parameter):
[always] madvise never

Process Memory:
Virtual Size: 1604356K (peak: 1604356K)
Resident Set Size: 162700K (peak: 308108K) (anon: 162536K, file: 164K, shmem: 0K)
Swapped out: 172408K
C-Heap outstanding allocations: 44874K

/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max (system-wide limit on the number of threads):
4571
/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count (maximum number of memory map areas a process may have):
65530
/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max (system-wide limit on number of process identifiers):
32768

container (cgroup) information:
container_type: cgroupv1
cpu_cpuset_cpus: 0
cpu_memory_nodes: 0
active_processor_count: 1
cpu_quota: -1
cpu_period: 100000
cpu_shares: -1
memory_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_and_swap_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_soft_limit_in_bytes: -1
memory_usage_in_bytes: 333606912
memory_max_usage_in_bytes: 0

KVM virtualization detected
Steal ticks since vm start: 0
Steal ticks percentage since vm start:  0.000

CPU:total 1 (initial active 1) (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 79 stepping 0 microcode 0x1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx, fma
CPU Model and flags from /proc/cpuinfo:
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear spec_ctrl intel_stibp arch_capabilities
Online cpus:
0
Offline cpus:

BIOS frequency limitation:
<Not Available>
Frequency switch latency (ns):
<Not Available>
Available cpu frequencies:
<Not Available>
Current governor:
<Not Available>
Core performance/turbo boost:
<Not Available>

Memory: 4k page, physical 601120k(170480k free), swap 1662968k(1_256_904k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.11+9-LTS) for linux-amd64 JRE (11.0.11+9-LTS), built on Apr 21 2021 14:19:55 by "mockbuild" with gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

END.
```

**Edit 1:**
The whole uncensored report file is [here](https://github.com/readren/javaOomReportForSO/blob/main/hs_err_pid19661.log)

Comment: You removed "Dynamic libraries" from the report, but that's exactly the memory map of the JVM process. You may also use [Native Memory Tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/troubleshoot/diagnostic-tools.html#GUID-1F53A50E-86FF-491D-A023-8EC4F1D1AC77) to find the memory usage of JVM structures.

Comment: Take a look at my [answer](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/1438#issuecomment-693637417) how to launch Java in a memory restricted environment.

Comment: @apangin Ups. I thought the dynamic libraries are irrelevant. I am editing the question to add them, but in a separated section because the list is large.
After that I will follow your links.